# Python Curses - Printing Ascii Art

Tags: python, ascii, curses

I have a long multi-line ascii art string that I would like to present to the user using the Python curses module. I am a bit confused as to approaching this, as the only method to print a string in curses is addstr(y,x,string), which only prints to one line. Any ideas on how this could be accomplished?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Loop over the lines, using `str.splitlines()`:

```
for y, line in enumerate(ascii_art.splitlines(), 2):
    w.addstr(y, 2, line)
```

This uses `enumerate()` to keep track of the `y` position, putting the whole ascii-art string on the screen starting at position (2, 2).

Comment: Thank you for the prompt response! I have a thing I must attend now, but I will test the code right when I return.